# Let $\pi$ be a plane with the equation $x-2y+2z=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Searching for some help with the following problem.

Let $\pi$ be a plane with the equation $x-2y+2z=0$. I need to find the matrix $P$ such that $\mbox{proj}_{\pi}(u)=Pu$ for all $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Not quite sure how to approach this question.

Comment: Hint: If you form a orthogonal basis $\{n,v_1,v_2\}$ starting with the normal vector $n$ of $\pi$ then $P$ is characterized by $Pn=0$ and $Pv_j=v_j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
x - 2y + 2z = 0 \iff \\
(1, -2, 2) \cdot (x,y,z) = 0 \
$$
So $n = (1,-2,2) / 3$ is a unit normal vector to the plane.

I assume that $\text{proj}_{\pi}(u)$ is supposed to return the part of $u$ that lies within the plane $\pi$. This would be
$$
u' = u - (u \cdot n) n
$$
In matrix form $u' = P u$ we would have
$$
P =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 - n_x n_x & -n_y n_x  & -n_z n_x \\
-n_x n_y & 1-n_y n_y  & -n_z n_y \\
-n_x n_z & -n_y n_z  & 1-n_z n_z \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
8/9 & 2/9  & -2/9 \\
2/9 & 5/9  & 4/9 \\
-2/9 & 4/9  & 5/9 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: is this the final solution?

Comment: how do you go about that? thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

Hint. The unit vector $n:=\frac{1}{3}(1,-2,2)$ is normal to the given plane $\pi$.

What is the geometric meaning of the vector  $\langle u,n\rangle n$ (where $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$ denotes the scalar product)?

Is it related with $Pu$?

Comment: Why divide by $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: @Guacho Perez Sorry,my silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can try and find three different points in the plane by solving the equation, call them $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}$. Then, $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{c}$ and $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{c}$ are two vectors contained in the plane. Put these two vectors into a matrix $\mathbf{P}$, and then you can apply the formula for the projection matrix $\mathrm{proj}_{\pi}=\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{P})^{-1}\mathbf{P}^T$